# code to query the table and produce a country code grouped and plot bar plot

Tags: r, postgresql, aggregate

Am new with R, and have managed to connect R to a database in PostgreSQL, so I want to query this database in R and produce a simple bar plot.   This bar plot should give an aggregated count of the top 5 countries codes.

can anyone suggest a query/script that would do just that?

it's basically a breakdown of countries, and how many people are each country.

I want to break down my data into countries and then the top 5 of those countries

sorry my data look something like this

country_code
GB

NL

US

GB

GB

NA

FR

I want to count how many of each and then plot the top 5 of those, how do you do this in R

Comment: *can anyone suggest a query/script that would do just that?* ...SO is not a code-writing service. Please make an earnest attempt and return with issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sort of a general overview of how I would connect and query:

```r
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con <- dbConnect(pg, user = "username", password = "your_password",
                 host="localhost", port = 5432, dbname = "dbname")

tbl(con, "table_name") %>% 
  group_by(country_code) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total)) %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  collect() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(country_code, -total), total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Thank you, your code worked really well. just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I went on a leg and presumed that oyu needed the top 5 countries with the most incidents.

Next time please post you reproducible data see dput()

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(countries) %>% 
  summarise(sum_incidents = sum(incidents)) %>%
  top_n(5) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = fct_reorder(countries,sum_incidents,.desc = TRUE), y = sum_incidents) +
  geom_col()
```

**Data**

```
incidents <- floor(runif(104, min=0, max=101))

countries <- rep(letters,4)

df <- tibble(incidents,countries)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have posted it now,